# Explanation of Bitwise NOT Operator

Tags: bitwise-operators

Why is it that the bitwise NOT operator (`~` in most languages) converts the following values like so:

`-2 -> 1`
`-1 -> 0`
`0 -> -1`
`1 -> -2`

Shouldn't `-2` convert to `2`, `1` convert to `-1`, etc.?

Comment: Addendum: useful to note that `bitwise NOT` is almost always the quickest to parse a string into a number: https://jsperf.com/number-vs-plus-vs-toint-vs-tofloat/20

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for the representation of negative integers in many languages. As you can see, -2 is represented by `1111110`; if you invert all those bits  you get `0000001`, i.e. a value of 1.

Comment: what about ~0? I couldn't get it. Please help

Comment: it is -1 .... ~(0000) = 1111 ....  convert 1111 to decimal by reverse-two's complement: 1111 - 1 = 1110 -> 0001 = 1 -> -1.  ultimately the mathematical function for what bitwise NOT does to a number is `~x = (-1 * (x+1))`

Comment: @Vicrobot follow the above provided link for more detail. Bitwise works on the binary level, so 0 on binary would seen as 0000_0000, and (in two's complemented) -1 is 1111_1111, this not 0 flips all the bits to 1s, thus alters 0 into -1. But in an unsigned type (like C# uint) it'll be the max value possible.

Answer (score 15):

It helps if you look at it in binary.

First of all, as you know, negative numbers are expressed as (highest possible unsigned number plus 1 minus value). So -1 in a 16-bit integer, which has the highest unsigned value of 65535, would be 65536-1=65535, i.e. 0xffff in hex, or `1111 1111 1111 1111` in binary.

So:

1 in binary = `0000 0000 0000 0001`

NOT on all bits would result in `1111 1111 1111 1110`. That, in decimal, is 65534. And 65536 minus 65534 is 2, so this is -2.

Answer (score 2):

Most (all?) modern architectures use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed integers. The bitwise NOT is thus the *complement* of the integer minus one.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Dim mask As Integer = -1
'11111111111111111111111111111111

For x As Integer = -3 To 3
    Dim i As Integer = x
    Debug.WriteLine("")
    Debug.WriteLine("'" & Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c) & " > Num = " & i.ToString)

    i = i Xor mask 'reverse the bits (same as Not)
    Debug.WriteLine("'" & Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c) & " > Not = " & i.ToString)

    i += 1 'convert to two's complement
    Debug.WriteLine("'" & Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c) & " > 2's Comp = " & i.ToString)
Next

'debug results

'11111111111111111111111111111101 > Num = -3
'00000000000000000000000000000010 > Not = 2
'00000000000000000000000000000011 > 2's Comp = 3

'11111111111111111111111111111110 > Num = -2
'00000000000000000000000000000001 > Not = 1
'00000000000000000000000000000010 > 2's Comp = 2

'11111111111111111111111111111111 > Num = -1
'00000000000000000000000000000000 > Not = 0
'00000000000000000000000000000001 > 2's Comp = 1

'00000000000000000000000000000000 > Num = 0
'11111111111111111111111111111111 > Not = -1
'00000000000000000000000000000000 > 2's Comp = 0

'00000000000000000000000000000001 > Num = 1
'11111111111111111111111111111110 > Not = -2
'11111111111111111111111111111111 > 2's Comp = -1

'00000000000000000000000000000010 > Num = 2
'11111111111111111111111111111101 > Not = -3
'11111111111111111111111111111110 > 2's Comp = -2

'00000000000000000000000000000011 > Num = 3
'11111111111111111111111111111100 > Not = -4
'11111111111111111111111111111101 > 2's Comp = -3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how negative numbers are represented as bits. For this most commonly [Two's Complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) are used.

-2 happens to be 1111110 in this notation, which negated is 1

Answer (score 0):

This is because the bit-wise operator literally inverts each bit in the word.
It is NOT strictly an arithmetic operation, it is a logic operation.

```
-2 == %1110, ~-2 == ~%1110 = %0001 == 1
-1 == %1111, ~-1 == ~%1111 = %0000 == 0
```

and so on.

To go from -2 to 2, and 1 to -1 you need to use the arithmetic negation operation.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in computer systems are stored as 2 complementary.
If number is positive then 2 complement of positive number is same.But for the negative number it is different.

1. `-2 -> 1`

   Here -2 will be stored in computer as 1110 (i.e. 2's complement of -2). Now `~` of 1110 is 0001. As 0001 is positive number it will be stored in computer as 0001 (i.e. 1)
2. `-1 -> 0`

   Here -1 will be stored in computer as 1111 (i.e. 2's complement of -1). Now `~` of 1111 is 0000.As 0000 is positive number it will be stored in computer as 0000 (i.e. 0)
3. `0 -> -1`

   Here 0 will be stored in computer as 0000 (i.e. 2's complement of 0). Now `~` of 0000 is 1111. As 1111 is negative number it will be stored in computer as 0001 (i.e. -1) (since MSB is set for 1111 the number will be negative)
4. `1 -> -2`

   Here 1 will be stored in computer as 0001 (i.e. 2's complement of 1). Now `~` of 0001 is 1110. As 1110 is negative number it will be stored in computer as 0010 (i.e.-2) (since MSB is set for 1110 the number will be negative)