# why is the bitwise complement of 10 is -11

Tags: c

Why the result of ~10 is -11? Shouldn't it be 5 as the ~ operations flips every bit.

10 = 1010

~10= 0101 //5 in decimal

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    unsigned int b =10;
    b= ~b;
    printf("bitwise %d\n ",b);     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement - also, `int`s should have 32 bits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explanation of Bitwise NOT Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295578/explanation-of-bitwise-not-operator)

Comment: Also, that's not how fixed-width integers work. Get yourself a basic math and hardware book.

Comment: Given an 8-bit integer, you flip _all_ of the bits, including the leading zeros. In other words, 10 is actually 00001010, not just 1010. Flip them and you get 11110101, which is -11, or 245 if using an unsigned integer. If it was a 4-bit integer, yes, you would get 5. By the way, `%d` is for signed decimal integers. You want `%u` since your integer is unsigned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget that you are flipping *every* bit, including the most significant bit (sign bit for signed variables). Defining a variable as unsigned doesn't change the binary representation, only how the program uses it.

So when you print the number out as signed (`%d`) you will get -11.

```
 10 = 0x0000000A (10)
~10 = 0xFFFFFFF5 (-11 signed / 4294967285 unsigned)
```

To print out as unsigned use:

```
printf("bitwise %u\n ",b);
```

Comment: unsigned values don't but if you're using them as signed value then they do. `unsigned` vs `signed` doesn't change binary representation. Also oops i typed that wrong, thanks for the correction.

Comment: You can still not call that a "sign bit" for an unsigned int, it is the Most Significant Bit participating in the variable value, interpreted as a sign bit by printf with an incorrect false print formatter.

Comment: @Étienne I see, you and Andrey are correct, I'll modify my answer so it isn't misleading. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Serdalis: Not really. Supplying an `unsigned` value to `printf` with `%d` modifier is only allowable if the actual value falls into the positive range of `int` (the language guarantees that representations match). In all other cases it is simply undefined behavior. In general case saying that `%d` in `printf` will "use unsigned value as signed value" is incorrect.

Answer (score 15):

Many things wrong with this.

1. You're bit-negating an unsigned int and then printing it as a signed int (`%d` is for signed integers). Print the result as an unsigned int and you will realize...
2. on a 32bit-`int` machine, `10`(decimal) is not `1010`(binary) but `000000000000000000000000000001010`.
3. Finally, convert everything back to signed integers and learn about two's complement notation to find out how negative numbers are stored in your computer.