# Best way to convert result of .indexOf to a Boolean using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering, say I had some thing like the following:

```
console.log(element.find('div').eq(3).text().indexOf('whatever'));
```

bearing in mind that `element` is defined and the console is logging a value of 32 (or anything that isn't -1) what would be the best way of converting the result into a Boolean so my `console.log` either outputs `true` or `false`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `element.find('div').eq(3).text().indexOf('whatever') > -1 `

Comment: `!!~something.indexOf('whatever')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
console.log(element.find('div').eq(3).text().indexOf('whatever') > -1);
```

Answer (score 15):

The answer above will work, however if you are as nerdy as I, you will far prefer this:

`console.log(~element.find('div').eq(3).text().indexOf('whatever'));`

The obscure '~' operator in javascript performs the operation "value * -1 - 1", e.g. `~-2 === 1.`  The only use case I have ever had for this is in converting the "not found" -1 from ".indexOf()" into "0" (a falsey value in javascript), follow through and see it will convert an index found at position "0" to "-1", a truthy value.

tldr:

```
~[1,2,3].indexOf(0) // => 0
!!~[1,2,3].indexOf(0) // => false

~[1,2,3].indexOf(1) // => -1
!!~[1,2,3].indexOf(1) // => true
```

Comment: You may want to revise your answer, as `~` is not really obscure. It is the bitwise NOT operator, which switches all 1s to 0s in the binary representation of your number. since -1 is `111....1` in binary, it turns to `000....0` which can be cast to `false`. ... better explanation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295578/explanation-of-bitwise-not-operator

Comment: From my tests, both this solution and the accepted solution run at roughly the same time. Ergo, if performance is your concern; it needn't be - choose the solution you prefer for readability.