# Why binarysearch method reduces the negative returned value by 1

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Talking about this method defined in Arrays:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int key)
```

I couldn't get the point behind why return `(-(insertion point) - 1)` instead of `-(insertion point)` in case of no match found in array.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)

Could it be the reason that `Math.abs((-(insertion point) - 1))` equals size of the array?

If you are wondering why I am asking this at all, I see that to find the insertion point I have to basically do the subtraction.

```
int returnedVal = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, needle);
if (returnedVal < 0) 
     insertionPoint = Math.abs(returnedVal) - 1;
```

Comment: If you believe the substraction is too verbose and error prone (it's easy to get the order backwards) you can just do  `insertionPoint =  ~returnedVal` (see edit in my answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because 0 is a legitimate insertion point, but you can't just return 0 because that would mean the key was found at index 0.

Edit: note that the choice of substracting 1 rather than another number is not arbitrary.  `-a - 1` equals `~a` (the bitwise negation of a), that function is bijective for all positive (and negative) integers because is just flipping the bits and uses the entire Integer range: `~Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MAX_VALUE` , `~(-1) == 0`. Also note that `~(~a) == a`.

You can find the insertion point by doing `~returnedVal`. Integers in Java always use two's complement so the equivalence is valid.

Using any subtrahend higher than 1 would cause an integer underflow for the highest indexes near Integer.MAX_VALUE.  For more information about the ~ operator see [Explanation of Bitwise NOT Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295578/explanation-of-bitwise-not-operator).

Answer (score 2):

No, the insertion point doesn't necessarily equal the size of the array; the item in question could theoretically be inserted at any point in the array.

It is possible for the item not to be found but also to be less than all items in the (sorted) array.  This would mean that the insertion point is `0`.  But using `-(insertion point)` would mean that `0` would be returned.  This means that the item was *found* at position `0`.  They subtract one to avoid this collision, so that an item less than all others would return `-1`.

Sure, you have to add one and then negate to find the insertion position if you really wanted to insert an item into the array.  But doing a little extra math is negligible considering you'd have to move contents of the array to make room for the new item in the array.

The binary search process does the work of finding the insertion point.  If it simply returned `-1` you'd have to redo the search to find the insertion point.  The method is giving you a little extra information when returning a "not found" scenario, which can be used if needed to insert the item into the array.  It just needed to avoid the case where 0 could mean "found at first position" and "not found, but insert at the beginning".