# Bitwise Operators NOT

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I encountered a problem with bit arithmetic. It is bitwise **NOT**.

if `A = 5;` then `~A = ?`

The binary of 5 is `101`, the inverse is `010`, and then converted to decimal is `0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0 = 2`

But when I test in the IDE, the output is as follows:

```java
System.out.println( ~5 );
```

Output:

```java
-6
```

I don't know why. Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? If so, start the calculator, switch to programmer mode using the hamburger menu at the top left, type `5` and look at the binary value. Then click the *Bitwise* menu (the downarrow next to the word) and choose `OR` from that menu. Look at the bits. You can find a link to twos-complement math in [Explanation of Bitwise OR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295578/explanation-of-bitwise-not-operator?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you using a standard `int`, then after assignment your A to 5:

int A = 5;

Then your "A" would be not `101b`, but `00000000000000000000000000000101b` - all 32 bits.

After `NEG` operation, which inverse all bits, you will get:

A = 11111111111111111111111111111010

And this int-value is `-6`, in the [2-complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), used int the most of computers.