# Why is ~x = -x -1

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit

I don't understant why ~x = -x-1 is true. It seems counter-intuitive to me to take the inverse when negating a number. Shouldn't -x just be x with the -/+ bit as 1?
Or is this  ~x = -x-1 just a hard set rule...

Comment: Duplicate of [Explanation of Bitwise NOT Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295578/explanation-of-bitwise-not-operator)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qH4unVtJkE and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qH4unVtJkE

Comment: There is no -/+ bit (there is a sign bit, but that's not how it works). Also consider `-1 - x`, at every position you're subtracting a bit of x from a set bit, inverting the bit without borrowing from the next position, therefore it must result in `~x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `~` operator flip all the bits. While `-x` is taking the minus of a certain value which is different. This is because the bit-wise operator inverts each bit in the word. It is not an arithmetic operation, it is a logic operation.

Let's consider the following example that will emphasize this issue for words of length 3:

*The range of values that you can represent is from -4 to 3.* If you are not familiar with it read about [2's complementnt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

`011` represent the value 3 -> `~3` is `100` which is -4.

Where -3 is `101` and when subtracting 1 you get `100` which is 4.

so when taking the negative value we need to also subtract 1 because the range is `-2^(B) - 2^(B) - 1` and we need to compensate.